# can sed add a new line after matching a pattern while not editing line pattern is on?

Tags: sed, find, replace

I need to find a way to add a line to files after a pattern, but I don't want to edit the line the pattern is on.

For example, my original file will look something like

```
group: misc
host: server1
job: internal
```

and I'd like to get it to something like

```
group: misc
host: server1
role: webserver
job: internal
```

The difficulty is i need to match on "host:" but the name after host will be different every time. I haven't found a way for sed to respect the rest of the line, and instead dumps the new lines immediately after finding "host:" leaving the hostname orphaned after the new line.

Comment: Is the original file in a structured format such as YAML? If it is, then the order is not important, and adding a new key+value is a s easy as `yq -y --arg role "webserver" '. += $ARGS.named' file` (using [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) and with `-i` added, you get in-place edit).

Comment: yeah, if this is yaml, then `sed` (and regexes in general) are the wrong tool, and you should use a yaml parser

Answer (score 5):

`a`ppend text after a match:

```
sed '/^host: /a\
role: webserver
' sample
```

---

Or `i`nsert a line before a match:

```
sed '/^job: /i\
role: webserver
' sample
```

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to [Marcus's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709141/22222), replace the end of line (`$`) with a a newline and the line you want to insert on lines that start with `host:`:

```
$ sed '/host: / s/$/\nrole: webserver/ ' file
group: misc
host: server1
role: webserver
job: internal
```

This will require GNU `sed` (or any other `sed` implementation that supports it) for the `\n` on the right-hand side. If the above fails, try:

```
$ sed '/host: / s/$/\
role: webserver/' file
group: misc
host: server1
role: webserver
job: internal
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is a pretty basic regex: use `.*` to match *everything*, an *arbitrary amount of times*; since sed is line-based, anyways, that only works till the end of each line.

So, your full GNU sed call is

```
sed 's/^host: .*$/&\nrole: webserver/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^host.*/{p;s//role: webserver/}' input_file
group: misc
host: server1
role: webserver
job: internal
```